# Move player's speed based on how far I push the analog stick/ joystick?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ive created a character controller system already, but his movement speed does not change based on how far I push the analog stick. I'm very new to Unity and c# and would like some help. Thanks! Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public Transform cam;

    public float speed = 6f;

    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
 
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        UnityEngine.Vector3 direction = new UnityEngine.Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical);

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            transform.rotation = UnityEngine.Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f);

            UnityEngine.Vector3 moveDir = UnityEngine.Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * UnityEngine.Vector3.forward;
            controller.Move(moveDir * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `speed = direction.magnitude`

Answer (score 0):

I think there are other ways of doing it but you can use animation for achieving that you adjust the trigger for the animation ! Example (play the slow animation if your speed is this and play speed animation if your speed is more)

Answer (score 0):

Also you should do this speed = direction.magnitude because  direction.magnitude holds the value of analog movement so animation plus this equals to a cool game good luck :)